# How to use SqlAlchemy to connect Database similar to cx_oracle when we use external authorization like wallets with TNS(net service name)

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

Consider below code:-
Now the below works

```py
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn = 'DSNAME')
```

But when I use below format for SqlAlchemy it doesn't work, I get `TypeError: Invalid arguments dsn passed`:

```py
connection = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://' , dsn = 'DSNAME')
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy requires a database connection URI, there is an article about it on [their documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/oracle.html#dsn-vs-hostname-connections). It requires the format

`oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@host:port/dbname[?key=value&key=value...]`

Have you tried the following?

```py
connection = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://' + 'DSNAME')
```

Comment: Great, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

it seems pretty old post, I tried with below code, it works . hope this helps. providing empty username/passwd, they are read from wallet, location is mentioned in sqlnet.ora

tnsnames.ora:

t1 = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ip)(PORT=1521)(KEY=dbpdb1))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=dbsvc1.oracle.com))).

sqlnet.ora:

WALLET_LOCATION =
(SOURCE =
(METHOD = FILE)
(METHOD_DATA =
(DIRECTORY = $walletdir)
)
)
SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
cstr='oracle://:@t1'
print(cstr)
engine = create_engine(
        cstr,
        convert_unicode=False,
        echo=True
        )
s='select * from emp'
conn = engine.connect()
result = conn.execute(s)
for row in result:
    print (row)
```